# Dynamic how to execute using nested objects, arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

Working as expected.
i have using this body of JSON passing to JavaScript its insert into SQL table.
**Input**

```
data : 
[{
    "name": "John",
    "detail" : "contact",
    "type" : "phone",
    "value"  : "987-654-3210"
},
{    "name": "John",
    "detail" : "contact",
    "type" : "email",
    "value"  : "john123@xyz.com"
},
{    "name": "John",
    "detail" : "address",
    "type" : "city",
    "value"  : "Berlin"
},
{   "name": "John",
    "detail" : "address",
    "type" : "country",
    "value"  : "Germany"
}]
```

**Javascript Process**

```
var data;
var rawdata =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

var query= ""

arrayLength = rawdata.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) { 

query +=` begin
          insert into [dbname].[dbo].[table] (name,detail,type,value) 
         values('` + rawdata[i].name+ `','` + rawdata[i].detail + `','` + rawdata[i].type+ `','` + 
             '` + rawdata[i].value + `')
            end       
}
return query;
```

**SQL table Output**

```
| name     | detail   |type     |value           |
| -------- | -------- |---------|----------------|
| John     | contact  |phone    |987-654-3210    |
| John     | contact  |email    |john123@xyz.com |
| John     | address  |city     |Berlin          |
| John     | address  |country  |Germany         |
```

Below i have this body of JSON.
How to pass to JavaScript function to insert into SQL table?

**Input**

```
{
    "data": [{
        "name": "John",
        "contact": {
            "phone": "987-654-3210",
            "email": "john123@xyz.com"
        },
        "address": {
            "city": "Berlin",
            "country": "Germany"
        }
    }]
}
```

**SQL table Output**

```
| name     | detail   |type     |value           |
| -------- | -------- |---------|----------------|
| John     | contact  |phone    |987-654-3210    |
| John     | contact  |email    |john123@xyz.com |
| John     | address  |city     |Berlin          |
| John     | address  |country  |Germany         |
```

How to create JavaScript function ? Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define helper function `buildQuery`, which uses `map` to create SQL strings from the passed arguments:
`name`, `rootKey` and its value entries, such as `["phone", "987-654-3210"]`.

`buildQueries` function destructures the argument data to be passed to the `buildQuery` and uses `Object.entries()` to extract the array of `[key, value]` pairs from the objects.

```js
const data = {
"data": [{
    "name": "John",
    "contact": {
        "phone": "987-654-3210",
        "email": "john123@xyz.com"
    },
    "address": {
        "city": "Berlin",
        "country": "Germany"
    }
}]
};


const buildQuery = (name, rootKey, entries) => 
  entries.map(([key, value]) => `begin insert into [dbname].[dbo].[table] (name, rootKey, type, value) values('${name}', '${rootKey}', '${key}', '${value}') end;`);

const buildQueries = ({ data: [{ name, contact, address }] }) => [
...buildQuery(name, 'contact', Object.entries(contact)),
...buildQuery(name, 'address', Object.entries(address))
  ].join('\n');

const query = buildQueries(data);
console.log(query);
```